# Using AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver

Tags: android, ios, appium

Just want to get clarity on the driver type that I need to use for testing mobile app on Android and iOS devices.  My main goal is to keep the same code-base for the two platforms - although, keeping them separate would be easier to implement; but difficult to maintain.

Having said that, I am curious if the following code snippet will work in this situation.

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;

if ("iOS".equals(os)) {
    driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
} else {
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Yes the code snippet which you have mentioned will work for your situation.*

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;

if ("iOS".equals(os)) {
    driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
} else {
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
}
```

*The driver instance created will be of type MobileElement.*

Answer (score 0):

```
private AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement> _driver;
public readonly string platform = "iOS";

switch (platform)
        {
            case MobilePlatform.Android:
                _driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new 
Uri("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), driverOptions, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
                break;
            case MobilePlatform.IOS:
                _driver = new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new 
Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), driverOptions, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
                break;
        }
```

Comment: pleae add some description to clearify your solution or any other interested user.